# How to search for a space in a string with backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a webpage with a searchbox and when you type in a search string (one word) using Backbone.js, you get the records containing that word.  However, when you type in a word and a space, no records are returned.  The function I am using is:

```
searchStrings: function(search) {
    // if search string is visible
    if (this.model.detailsVisible && search != this.model.strings.searchName) {
        // set search string to searchName
        this.model.strings.searchName = search;
        var params = {data: {id: this.model.get('id')}, cache: false, add: true, merge: false, remove: false};
        if (search) params.data.string = search;

        this.model.strings.offset = 0;
        this.model.strings.totalResults = null;
        this.model.strings.remove(this.model.strings.filter(function(strings) {return !strings.selected;}));
        this.model.strings.fetch(params);
    }
}
```

Is there anything I have overlooked that would solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is to remove space characters around your word, you can use [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) method.

```
search = search.trim();
```

If the problem not in space characters, please provide code of collection inside your `this.model.strings`.